# Minify JavaScript file with Ant in eclipse IDE, Error: Missing Name After . Operator

Tags: javascript

I want to minify javascript file using Ant in my eclipse IDE. When I execute the compression, I have the following error in my console:

missing name after . operator

I have this error according to this line of code.

```
var myvariable1 = myvariable2;
myvariable2.then(function1(parameter1)).catch(function2(parameter2));
```

Could anyone help me to solve this issue and tell what's wrong in my code?

Comment: `var myvariable1 = myvariable1;` means `myvariable1` is `undefined`...

Comment: @ASDFGerte,  I am sorry, I have edited my question, var myvariable1 = myvariable1; should be var myvariable1 = myvariable2;